# Datatable become frozen while searching or sorting

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

After starting searching, data table becomes frozen with a message "processing.." (see the image).

I am using server-side processing (see the javascript code)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert('doc');

    $('#example').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "searching": true,
            "ordering": true,

            "ajax": "index.php?r=patient/list",
    });
});


<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>phone</th>
        <th>email</th>

    </tr>
</thead>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>phone</th>
        <th>email</th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

While searching an ajax call is made by data table return successfully with filtered data. It not displayed as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with returned data. There is param called the 'draw' should be incremented with each response.

```
$draw = $_GET['draw'];
$draw = $draw + 1;
$jsondata["draw"] = $draw;
echo json_encode($jsondata);
```